# npm: disable postinstall script for package

Tags: node.js, npm

Is it any npm option exist to disable `postinstall` script while installing package? Or for rewriting any field from `package.json`?

Comment: The question is very clear but...is by any chance _this_ your end-goal? https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#postinstall-message ;-)

Answer (score 425, accepted):

It's not possible to disable only `postinstall` script. However, **you can disable all scripts** using:

```
$ npm install --ignore-scripts
```

As delbertooo mentioned in the comments, this also disables the scripts of the dependencies.

Comment: Thx. This is exactly what I need. Where can I find such options? This is not described in 'npm help install', 'npm help config' and 'npm help scripts'.

Comment: I checked the code directly: https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/lib/build.js#L179

Comment: Caution! The option `--ignore-scripts` disables ALL scripts - even from your dependencies. If your dependencies need to run scripts to e.g. install some binaries they may break / be incomplete.

Comment: So is there a technique then to install node_modules (and all their scripts) but ignore only the main package's scripts ?

Comment: Not only this, but `--ignore-scripts`, or the associated config option (which I set globally) will also mean that `npm run start` will silently do nothing and report success. Amaze.

Comment: how to execute scripts after doing `npm install?`

Answer (score 45):

You can also enable the settings in npm configuration file.

`npm config set ignore-scripts true`

Note: This will disable scripts for all NPM packages.

Comment: This should be the answer. See npm blog post: https://blog.npmjs.org/post/141702881055/package-install-scripts-vulnerability

Comment: Note that it also disables the ability to manually execute `npm run …` - it will simply do nothing, without any warning.

Comment: does this work for yarn too?

Answer (score 24):

I wanted to disable postinstall script for my project but wanted all scripts of my project's dependencies to run when I do `npm install`.
This is what I ended up doing.

1. Create a script `./scripts/skip.js`

```js
if (process.env.SKIP_BUILD) {
    process.exit(0);
} else {
    process.exit(1);
}
```

2. In your package.json file

```
 "scripts": {
  ...
  "postinstall": "node ./scripts/skip.js || npm run build",
  ...
 }
```

now just set the environment variable SKIP_BUILD=1 to prevent your package from building and your dependencies will build just fine

```
SKIP_BUILD=1 npm install
```

Comment: Nice! I'd probably just do "postinstall": "node process.env.RUN_POSTINSTALL && npm run build" though

Comment: I attempted the solution in the comment based on RUN_POSTINSTALL and I couldn't get it to work. The original answer worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using NPM >= 8, you can also remove the `postinstall` script temporarily:

```bash
npm pkg set scripts.postinstall="echo no-postinstall"
npm install
```

Or with NPM 7, like so:

```bash
npm set-script postinstall ""
npm install
```

Source:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-set-script/

Answer (score 13):

To do this for your own library, I recommend something simple like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## this is your postinstall.sh script:

set -e;

if [ "$your_pkg_skip_postinstall" == "yes" ]; then
  echo "skipping your package's postinstall routine.";
  exit 0;
fi
```

then do your npm install with:

```
your_pkg_skip_postinstall="yes" npm install
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great if you're just trying to disable your own script but not ALL scripts in all dependencies.

Comment: @BrianNeisler yer very welcome, always feels good to help other people. By the way, I think double brackets [[ ]] might be better than single brackets for most use cases, not sure tho.

Answer (score 1):

Define `.npmrc` and set `ignore-scripts=true`.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions listed above worked as I had hoped.

Ultimately, I got the desired behavior I was looking for by:

1. Setting `postinstall` in my `package.json` to:

```json
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "4.3.6",
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "postinstall": "node ./scripts/postInstall",
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
     ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
     ...
  }
}
```

2. Creating a `scripts/postInstall.js` file with the following content:

```js
/* eslint-disable no-console */
const { spawn } = require('node:child_process');
const { exit } = require('process');

/**
 * In some cases like server releases we need to skip postinstall (unnecessary)
 * and yarn/npm does not support skipping postinstall without disabling all scripts which is dangerous
 * so this is a workaround that allows us to skip these steps.
 */
if (process.env.SKIP_POSTINSTALL) {
  console.log('Skipping postinstall steps');
  exit(0);
}

console.log('Running postinstall steps...');

// TODO: replace your `postinstall` command
const steps = spawn(
  'yarn patch-package && yarn run applovin:setup && yarn locales:pull -q && yarn update-env && yarn nx:postinstall',
  { shell: true },
);

steps.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString().replace(/[\r\n]/, ''));
});

steps.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`ERROR: ${data.toString()}`);
});

steps.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log('Post install steps complete!');
  exit(code);
});
```

3. Finally when I need to skip `postinstall` I run `SKIP_POSTINSTALL=1 yarn`