# Why is npm running prepare script after npm install, and how can I stop it?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

Whenever I run `npm install <package>` it installs the package alright, but then it automatically runs the `prepare` script.

It's worth mentioning that I've already checked that there is no `postinstall` script in the *package.json*.

Comment: Mind showing us some info in the package.json and show us the terminal when you run the command? It's hard to tell when we have nothing to go off of.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm: disable postinstall script for package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505318/npm-disable-postinstall-script-for-package)

Comment: Why do you want to stop it? Packages that have a prepare script usually expect it to be run to work properly.

Answer (score 46):

The other answers are fine, but for some additional context, this is to support a workflow where you can use devDependencies to build assets or other generated content for your project.

For example, say you want to use node-sass (CSS preprocessor).  You add "node-sass" as a devDependency, then you run the sass command in your "prepare" script, which generates your CSS.

So, when you run `npm install`, the following happens:

- dependencies and devDependencies get installed
- your "prepare" script generates your CSS
- your project is ready to go with all necessary CSS

And when you run `npm publish`, something similar happens:

- your "prepare" script generates your CSS
- your code and generated CSS are published to the npm repo

So now when someone comes along and installs your package, they don't need node-sass or any of your devDependencies.  They only need the runtime deps.

Comment: This the only answer here which actually understands and answers the question

Comment: So this appears to not have a solution than and npm messed this up? Cause this work flawlessly in yarn .

Comment: Is there anything like prepare that only runs on `npm install` local / relative and not packages which consume the dependency?

Comment: @Nick if yarn isn't behaving as described here, then yarn is broken.

Comment: @Nick, if I'm understanding you correctly, `npm install` and "prepare" already does what you describe.  "prepare" scripts aren't executed for dependencies because it's expected they were run at time of publish.

Comment: It’s doesn’t work npm install runs prepare under the hood for all sub dependencies as well on post install.

Comment: That’s not what I observe in npm maybe it’s a bug in 7.x , haven’t gone to 8 yet thinking about going back to 6 or to pnpm.

Comment: Wrote this for the exact problem as a work around https://github.com/nmccready/skip-npm-task

Answer (score 39):

From https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts:

> prepare: Run both BEFORE the package is packed and published, and on
>   local npm install without any arguments (See below). This is run AFTER
>   prepublish, but BEFORE prepublishOnly.

Since NPM v5, `prepare` script is executed when you run `npm install`

Comment: "local npm install" is when you `git clone <github.com/thepackage>` and then do `cd thepackage` and run `npm install`, as opposed to when you install the package from the registry with `npm install <thepackage>`

Comment: Hey @boris! I understand the confusion - I believe the updated NPM docs are more clear about this now - https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install Specifically "If the package being installed contains a prepare script, its dependencies and devDependencies will be installed, and the prepare script will be run, before the package is packaged and installed."

Answer (score 29):

The `prepare` script runs on local install and when installing git dependencies:

> **prepare:** Run both BEFORE the package is packed and published, on local npm install without any arguments, and when installing git dependencies (See below). This is run AFTER prepublish, but BEFORE prepublishOnly.
>
> https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

You can avoid it with the `--ignore-scripts` flag:

```
$ npm install <package> --ignore-scripts
```

source: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: This can cause other problems. Some packages expect scripts to be run to be usable. This globally disables all scripts, just for this run, and can cause other issues. Be careful!

Answer (score 8):

From the doc https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

> prepare: Run both BEFORE the package is packed and published, and on local npm install without any arguments (See below). This is run AFTER prepublish, but BEFORE prepublishOnly.

`prepare` script run before publishing and after `npm install`.

Now if you make an `npm install` and one of the packages has a `prepare` script, like for building, and it fails the whole install will fail.

We have two options:

### Ignore scripts

```
npm install --ignore-scripts
```

That will run the ignore to all packages, which might be not the desired behavior. Imagine a third party package that needs to run `prepare` and `build`. If you run with `--ignore-scripts` this will get skipped.

### Make the script optional (better option)

Add a package to the `optionalDependencies`:

```json
{
   optionalDependencies: {
       "myPackage": "^1.0.0"
   }
}
```

> If a dependency can be used, but you would like npm to proceed if it cannot be found or fails to install, then you may put it in the `optionalDependencies` object. This is a map of package name to version or url, just like the `dependencies` object. The difference is that build failures do not cause installation to fail.

> Entries in `optionalDependencies` will override entries of the same name in `dependencies`, so it's usually best to only put in one place.

Check the doc:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#optionaldependencies

**Note:** With this, only the chosen package is concerned. And if it fails the installation will continue. That's usually what you want.

#### Go with optionalDependencies

As per this answer in this thread:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2817#issuecomment-368661749

> the problem with --ignore-scripts is that is ignores all scripts. I just need to be able to ignore a script(s) for a particular package (the one where a build fails to compile on certain platforms). This option usually breaks my code because it has ignored ALL scripts in other packages that actually do need to run.

> Anyway, to make this work like the OP I make the offending package optional. Then do a regular install, then a second install with --ignore-scripts. That way I get the scripts of other packages run first before ignoring them all (including the intended) the second time which then "fetches" the source of that package.

It's generally better to go with `optionalDependencies`. That will most likely suit your needs.