# Triggering Prepare on NPM Install

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, typescript, npm

I am installing a typescript module via git. This module has a `package.json` file that includes a `prepare` script in its scripts section. However, it appears the `prepare` script is **not** executed on `npm install <git repository#version>`.

How can I have the `prepare` script executed on `npm install` via the git repository?

Comment: This was introduced in npm version 5. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The `prepare` script is not intended to be executed by package consumers, but only by the package owner.

This means you cannot execute the `prepare` script of any third-party package.

Create a `prepare` script, that is identical to the third-party package, in **your** package.json , but it will be executed only on command `npm install`, not on command `npm install '<git repository#version>'`

If you publish your own package and you want that `prepare` script is executed when a consumer installs your package, you have to create a `preinstall` script instead of a `prepare` script.

Comment: "you have to create a preinstall script instead of a prepare script" -- This is no longer true.  Since NPM v5, `prepare` is executed by `npm install`. See the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70228570/8910547) and the documentation it links to. See also [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499912/why-is-npm-running-prepare-script-after-npm-install-and-how-can-i-stop-it).