# How do I get `npm install` to compile my TypeScript module into JS when it is installed by a user?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm-install, npm-scripts, npm-publish

I built a TypeScript module and pushed it to GitHub. I now want to use this module inside my `MyApp` as a dependency which is also written in TypeScript. The package is registered in my `MyApp/package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "foo": "github:organization-xyz/foo",
  }
```

I added a command `build-ts` to create the corresponding `JavaScript` bindings inside my *foo* module `foo/package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build-ts": "tsc"
    ...
  },
```

Of course, this command is not executed when I call `npm i` on my main application. How would I properly prepare my module `foo` in order to import it successfully inside my app?

Comment: You commit the build artifacts. npm has no knowledge of typescript. You'll want to have a folder called dist or lib or whatever *in your library that you publish* with the compiled js and the .d.ts file for the types, and you'll set an entry point to that file in your package.json for your library. The .d.ts file will tell consuming typescript code what the types are.

Comment: If I execute `npm run build-ts` inside the dependency everything works. So you are saying publishing the artifacts to proceed is mandatory to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, the library typically compiles it to.js and .d.ts files. Take a look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html

Comment: Correct, that's what I have after the mentioned command. What a pity that I need to distribute them as an artifact as this could be done locally while installing the module

Comment: Why would you want to burden the user of the lib with compiling it? It only needs to be compiled once per version, not for every user of that library, adding time to their build. Imagine if every library did that? It's interesting to note that Angular libraries do get compiled by the client when an application is built for backwards compatibility reasons.

Comment: I grew up with `configure/make` so that's not unusual to me. But understood, thanks for the help! I would accept this as an answer

Comment: @JuanMendes, no it is NOT mandatory to publish the build artifacts. You are right that it isn't the recommended approach, but npm totally supports doing it as HelloWorld wants it. See my answer.

Comment: @Inigo Did I say it was mandatory? I said typically! And that's what's suggested by TypeScript!

Comment: @JuanMendes That's maybe what you meant, but it's not how your answer read. He asked "So you are saying publishing the artifacts to proceed is mandatory to achieve this?" and you answered "Yes". "Typically" as you used it modifies "compiles", not the "yes".

Comment: @Inigo Yes, my answer is the most common and suggested way. You would be fighting against the grain if you choose to do it. You are choosing to put meaning into my answer. By saying typically, I was leaving room for alternatives 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Put your build command in a `package.json` `prepare` script.

For example:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "npm run build-ts"
    "build-ts": "tsc"
    ...
  },
```

`prepare` is one of the
[Life Cycle Scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#life-cycle-scripts) that are automatically run by npm in certain situations. One of the situations is when package dependencies are installed, as stated in the [npm-install docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install):

> If the package being installed contains a prepare script, its dependencies and devDependencies will be installed, and the prepare script will be run, before the package is packaged and installed.

Since the prepare script is also run before publishing, be sure configure your `package.json` to not publish the build artifacts.

Since you mentioned that you are publishing it on GitHub, here is some more info specific to that case:

- [Installing and Building an NPM Package from Github - Jim Nielsen’s Blog](https://blog.jim-nielsen.com/2018/installing-and-building-an-npm-package-from-github/) - This one specifically discuses the use of npm `prepare` scripts.
- [Install NPM Packages from GitHub | Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/install-npm-packages-from-gitgithub)

### That said...

...if the build does not have dependencies on the install target (e.g. cpu-architecture), standard practice is to transpile your Typescript into Javascript before publishing. Pretty much everyone does this, including the makers of Typescript.  But I'm not going to make the case here...

Comment: I just tried it out and it works. That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much! 

Comment: Btw, I understand that once I make the module public, I will use the recommended approach