# Using --ignore-scripts for one dependency in NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505318/npm-disable-postinstall-script-while-install-package), NPM dependencies can be installed using:

`$ npm install --ignore-scripts`

Is there a way to mark that a dependency should be installed without running scripts in `package.json`?

This is because, when I run `npm install --ignore-scripts`, the dependency is added to `package.json`. As a result, other users will install the package while running scripts, however I want this certain package to never run scripts.

Comment: I have a similar issue and I am wondering if adding it to bundled/peer dependencies would work.

Comment: I was wondering how to do this as well. Did you find an answer? Best.

Comment: This article describes the command line tool `can-i-ignore-scripts`. It does provide an easy way to do the opposite of what you're asking for => When using `--ignore-scripts`, it gives a way to whitelist which dependencies SHOULD be allowed to run scripts. https://dev.to/naugtur/get-safe-and-remain-productive-with-can-i-ignore-scripts-2ddc

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I believe its: `npm install -ignore-script package-name@version`